# Cannot center img horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center image horizontally in this sample http://jsfiddle.net/3k3CC/1545/ , but I'm unsuccessfull. It only works when container is wider than image, but what I need is for the image to be centered even if the container is thinner than the image itself.

Sample CSS:

```
#artiststhumbnail {
    width:100px;
    height:308px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-color:#DADADA;     
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    background-color:pink;
}
#artiststhumbnail:hover {left:50px }
#genre {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#2A2A2A
}


#artiststhumbnail a img {
    display : block;
    margin : auto;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="artiststhumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <!--image here-->
        <img src="http://goo.gl/QrKCc" height="100%" alt="artist" border="1" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `text-align: center;` to `#thumbnailwrapper` and set `display: inline-block;` to `#artiststhumbnail`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3k3CC/1546/)

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry I don't unsderstand your question at the beggining. Use this simple CSS:

```
#artiststhumbnail a img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3k3CC/1553/)

Comment: Sorry your demo does not center the image, just the `#artiststhumbnail`

Comment: What I want is for the image to be centered when the container is thinner than the image itself.

Comment: See my edit and my [new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3k3CC/1553/) please :)

Comment: Thank you, added some prefixes and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the #artiststhumbnail this code,

```
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
```

http://codepen.io/jrey/pen/waXgBO updated code :)

try this CSS.. comment your css and try this please...

```
#artiststhumbnail {
    width:100px;
    height:308px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-color:#DADADA;     
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    background-color:pink;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}


#artiststhumbnail:hover {left:50px }
#genre {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#2A2A2A
}

#artiststhumbnail a  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#artiststhumbnail a img {
    display : block;
    margin : 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/ynj1hdjj/9/)

### CSS

```
    #thumbnailwrapper {
        color:#2A2A2A;
        margin-right:5px;
        border-radius:0.2em;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        background-color:#E9F7FE;
        padding:5px;
        border-color:#DADADA;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:thin;
        font-size:15px;
        /* The following rules make this a flexbox container */
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #thumbnailwrapper:hover {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px #DDDDDD
    }
    #artiststhumbnail {
        width:100px;
        height:308px;
        overflow:visible;  // Changed from hidden to visible 
        border-color:#DADADA;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:thin;
        background-color:pink;
    }
    #artiststhumbnail:hover {
        /*left:50px*/
    }
    /* No position: fixed. absolute, or relative; left: 50px has no effect on a static element */
     #genre {
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#2A2A2A
    }
    #artiststhumbnail a img {
        /* display: block;
         margin: auto; */
    }
    /* Removed margin and block display to demonstrate that flexbox container and it's children elements are not easily influenced by other element properties and attributes */
```

### HTML

```
<div id="thumbnailwrapper">
    <div id="artiststhumbnail"> <a href="#">
        <!--image here-->
        <img src="http://goo.gl/QrKCc" height="100%" alt="artist" border="1" />
    </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try your image width to 100%

```
#artiststhumbnail a img {
    display : block;
    margin : auto;
     width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by center but here it goes. If you want the image itself to center, use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` to accomplish this.

```
<div id="thumbnailwrapper">
<div id="artiststhumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <!--image here-->
        <div></div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>


#artiststhumbnail a div {
    display : block;
    margin : auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/QrKCc');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3k3CC/1552/)

EDIT: sorry, had the wrong jsfiddle link attached

Comment: @skmasq I'm quite aware what "center" means, thank you. Your question is ambiguous with regards to *what* you want to center. Try to fix that. Additionally, why would this solution not work with dynamic content when you can just set the background url with javascript?

Comment: center the entire 100px image block inside the div or the image itself in the 100px viewfinder. Even @imgonzalves had a problem understanding your question. "I'm sorry I don't unsderstand your question at the beggining."

Comment: @skmasq so I bring a valid point and you want to downvote it just because you don't know how to use javascript to set a background-url?